# How is it possible to fade-out a TextButton after it has been pressed?

Tags: libgdx

I simply want to fade-out (opacity = completely transparent) a button after I've pressed it... the following code has the unexplainable effect of fading the background image (a totally different actor!) to black !

What am I doing wrong ?

```
      Skin skin = new Skin();
      TextureAtlas buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("gfx/menu_buttons.pack"));
      skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
      TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
      textButtonStyle.font = mButtonSpacefont;
      textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("menu_button_background_top");
      textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("menu_button_background_bottom");
      mButtonStartGame = new TextButton("Play", textButtonStyle);
      mButtonStartGame.setPosition(game.getIdealWidth()/2 - mButtonStartGame.getWidth()/2,
            game.getIdealHeight()/2 - mButtonStartGame.getHeight()/2);

      mButtonStartGame.addListener(new ChangeListener()
      {
         @Override
         public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor)
         {
            //triggers when button is pressed and let go
            mButtonStartGame.addAction(Actions.fadeOut( 1.0f ));
          }
      });

      // add actors to stage
      mStage.addActor(backgroundActor);//background
      mStage.addActor(titleActor);//ontop of background
      mStage.addActor(mButtonStartGame);//ontop of background
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I've discovered that the TextButton is faded out - BUT - so is the actor that contains the background image `backgroundActor` ! Why would the backgroundActor be faded when the code doesn't even call `backgroundActor.addAction(Actions.fadeOut( 1.0f ));` ??

**UPDATE 2:**
The `render()` method seems to play a part... when I call `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);` the whole screen (except for the titleActor!) turns black due to the fadeOut action. When I call `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);` the whole screen (except for the titleActor!) turns white.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta)
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);//clear the screen black
    //Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);// no effect, so commented out
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // update the actors
    mStage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    // draw the actors
    mStage.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that all of my actor's need to take into consideration the `parentAlpha` and set the color with `batch.setColor()`.
Since my background was an actor, and I wasn't setting the batch color, the background was screwed up.

for example:

```
public class ActorBackground extends Actor
{
    // Member Variables
    private Texture mTexture;

    // Constructor
    public ActorBackground(GFXLoader gfxloader)
    {
        mTexture = new Texture(gfxloader.loadGraphic("menu_background"));// returns Gdx.files.internal(file.path())
        //setBounds(getX(), getY(), mTexture.getWidth(), mTexture.getHeight());
        setWidth(mTexture.getWidth());
        setHeight(mTexture.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha)
    {
        // needed to make actions work
        super.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        // needed to make fade work
        Color color = new Color(this.getColor().r, this.getColor().g, this.getColor().b, this.getColor().a * parentAlpha);
        batch.setColor(color);

        // show it
        batch.draw(mTexture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```